# How to calculate the area of a map in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the area of a watershed using the package maps, but have no success.

The link to download the polygon is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwVpSqmgvCe-a01ra2RtcTVZTGs

```
install.packages("maps");
library(maps)
tmarias <- readShapePoly("TrêsMarias_Poligon.shp")
m <- map(tmarias, fill = TRUE, plot = TRUE)
area.map(m)
```

The answer given by the code is 4.37, but it should be something about 50000 km².

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function `areaPolygon` to compute the area of a polygon in the geosphere package. It gives the area in square meters, but you can convert to sq.km.

```
library(geosphere)
areaPolygon(tmarias)
[1] 50766929868
areaPolygon(tmarias) / 1000000
[1] 50766.93       ## sq km
```

You can find many helpful tools at the 
[CRAN Task View: Analysis of Spatial Data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html)